# How to synchronise multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

How would you synchronise multiple threads to be at a certain place in their code at a particular time?

I am not looking for `WaitAll`, `await` etc. As in the example code, the threads do not return, only one thread is created per worker.

I have made this monster...
It works for simple and slow cases, but there is a race condition: when a fast thread locks `_sync` before the synchroniser. As a result sometimes that thread will execute more than once per cycle and break any assumptions of what is ready for use by other threads.

```
static readonly Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();

static readonly object _locker1 = new object();
static readonly object _locker2 = new object();
...
static readonly object _sync = new object();

static void Main()
{
    Task.Run(Synchroniser);
    Task.Run(DoWork1);
    Task.Run(DoWork2);
    ...
}

static void Synchroniser()
{
    while (true)
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            timer.Restart();
            while (timer.ElapseMilliseconds < 16) ;
            lock (_locker1) ;
            lock (_locker2) ;
            ...
        }
    }
}

static void DoWork1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        lock (_locker1)
        {
            //all worker threads continue from here at the same time
            ...
        }
        lock (_sync) ;
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure if [`Task.WaitAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netcore-3.1) is the kind of thing you're looking for or not.

Comment: Thread synchronization is a mighty large topic. Look into signaling mechanisms..., lock is probably not going to do it for you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what kind of behavior you're after, but I think this is what you're trying to achieve.  Run it and see how it behaves...

The code makes use of the [ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=netcore-3.1) class and the [WaitAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitall?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitAll_System_Threading_WaitHandle___) function:

```
class Program
{

    static readonly ManualResetEvent startWorkers = new ManualResetEvent(false); // workers initially blocked
    static readonly ManualResetEvent worker1 = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    static readonly ManualResetEvent worker2 = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    static readonly Random R = new Random();

    static void Main()
    {
        Task.Run(new Action(Synchroniser));
        Task.Run(new Action(DoWork1));
        Task.Run(new Action(DoWork2));

        Console.ReadLine(); // keep program from closing
    }

    static void Synchroniser()
    {
        ManualResetEvent[] workers = new ManualResetEvent[] { worker1, worker2 };
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pausing...");
            Thread.Sleep(5000); // long pause so we can see what is happening

            Console.WriteLine("Signalling workers.");
            startWorkers.Set(); // allow workers to run
            startWorkers.Reset(); // workers can only run ONCE until we set again

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for all workers to be done...");
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(workers); // wait for all the workers to be done
            Console.WriteLine("All workers are done.");
            worker1.Reset();
            worker2.Reset();
        }
    }

    static void DoWork1()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker1 waiting.");
            startWorkers.WaitOne(); // wait here until signalled

            // ... do something in here ...
            Console.WriteLine("Worker1 processing...");
            Thread.Sleep(R.Next(3000, 10000)); // random amount of work
            Console.WriteLine("Worker1 done.");

            worker1.Set(); // let Synchroniser know we are done
        }
    }

    static void DoWork2()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker2 waiting.");
            startWorkers.WaitOne(); // wait here until signalled

            // ... do something in here ...
            Console.WriteLine("Worker2 processing...");
            Thread.Sleep(R.Next(3000, 10000)); // random amount of work
            Console.WriteLine("Worker2 done.");

            worker2.Set(); // let Synchroniser know we are done
        }
    }

}
```

Sample output:

```
Worker1 waiting.
Pausing...
Worker2 waiting.
Signalling workers.
Waiting for all workers to be done...
Worker2 processing...
Worker1 processing...
Worker1 done.
Worker1 waiting.
Worker2 done.
Worker2 waiting.
All workers are done.
Pausing...
Signalling workers.
Waiting for all workers to be done...
Worker2 processing...
Worker1 processing...
Worker1 done.
Worker1 waiting.
Worker2 done.
Worker2 waiting.
All workers are done.
Pausing...
```

> If somehow the worker thread finishes before startWorkers.Reset();

I think it's unlikely to happen, but here's a two gate system that should prevent that from happening.  After signalling that the thread is done, it will sit and wait until all threads have completed before being allowed to continue:

```
class Program
{

    static readonly ManualResetEvent startWorkers = new ManualResetEvent(false); // workers initially blocked
    static readonly ManualResetEvent releaseWorkers = new ManualResetEvent(false); // workers initially blocked
    static readonly ManualResetEvent worker1 = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    static readonly ManualResetEvent worker2 = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    static readonly Random R = new Random();

    static void Main()
    {
        Task.Run(new Action(Synchroniser));
        Task.Run(new Action(DoWork1));
        Task.Run(new Action(DoWork2));

        Console.ReadLine(); // keep program from closing
    }

    static void Synchroniser()
    {
        ManualResetEvent[] workers = new ManualResetEvent[] { worker1, worker2 };
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pausing...");
            Thread.Sleep(5000); // long pause so we can see what is happening

            Console.WriteLine("Signalling workers.");
            startWorkers.Set(); // allow workers to run, automatically reset
            startWorkers.Reset();

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for all workers to be done...");
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(workers); // wait for all the workers to be done
            Console.WriteLine("All workers are done.");

            Console.WriteLine("Resetting workers...");
            // Reset all workers
            foreach(ManualResetEvent mre in workers)
            {
                mre.Reset();
            }

            // release the workers to wait at the top of their loops
            Console.WriteLine("Releasing workers...");
            releaseWorkers.Set();
            releaseWorkers.Reset();
        }
    }

    static void DoWork1()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker1 waiting.");
            startWorkers.WaitOne(); // wait here until signalled

            // ... do something in here ...
            Console.WriteLine("Worker1 processing...");
            Thread.Sleep(R.Next(3000, 10000)); // random amount of work

            Console.WriteLine("Worker1 done.");
            worker1.Set(); // let Synchroniser know we are done

            Console.WriteLine("Worker1 waiting for release...");
            releaseWorkers.WaitOne(); // wait for all clear                 
        }
    }

    static void DoWork2()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker2 waiting.");
            startWorkers.WaitOne(); // wait here until signalled

            // ... do something in here ...
            Console.WriteLine("Worker2 processing...");
            Thread.Sleep(R.Next(3000, 10000)); // random amount of work

            Console.WriteLine("Worker2 done.");
            worker2.Set(); // let Synchroniser know we are done

            Console.WriteLine("Worker2 waiting for release...");
            releaseWorkers.WaitOne(); // wait for all clear                 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is very good. But it seems that it is still not guaranteed to work. If somehow the worker thread finishes before `startWorkers.Reset();`. Though it is unlikely, the scheduler might just come up with some random trash. Is there no way to make this rigorous?

Comment: I'm thinking you could split `startWorkers` into `WorkersReady` and `WorkersGo` so that there is no time when both gates are open, but i might be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the `wait()` function and such for the `Task` class.
It provides a way to continue execution of the current thread when a Task or a given array of tasks finishes execution.

For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netcore-3.1

So for example:

```
static void Main()
{
    Task t1 = Task.Run(() => DoStuff_1("Task"));
    Task t2 = Task.Run(() => DoStuff_2("Task"));        

    Task.WaitAll({t1, t2}); // Blocks the current thread till the given tasks finish execution
}
```